# How to test int equality with ShouldBe

Tags: c#, shouldly

I am running c# tests using ShouldBe and I have this code:

```
int x = 3;
int y = 3;
x.ShouldBeSameAs(y);
```

Problem is it throws exception:

> An exception of type 'Shouldly.ShouldAssertException' occurred in
>   Shouldly.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: x

```
should be same as
```

3

```
but was
```

3

How can I test equality of to integers with ShouldBe?

Comment: I don't know what `shouldly.dll` is, but it seems to be comparing references. And since those references are not the same (x is not the same object as y) your assert fails. A quick look at the docs makes me wonder why you don;t use x.ShouldBe(y) in order to compare values.

Comment: @Uros Why not `Assert.AreEqual()`?

Comment: To test if it is really reference equality that is being tested for, you could try `int value = 3; object boxX = value; object boxY = boxX; boxX.ShouldBeSameAs(boxY);`. Here `boxX` and `boxY` are reference to the same box (instance of a boxed value).

Comment: @royalTS: Shouldly has nicer messages when condition is not satisfied, so it makes it easier to figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the documentation `ShouldBeSameAs` uses reference equality.

Use `ShouldBe`.

See documentation [here](https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly).

Answer (score 4):

Just use `ShouldBe`:

```
x.ShouldBe(y);
```